# PHP curl login to page

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a little problem, trying to make one script that sends sms, but I need to authenticate fist... My first thoughts was PHP CURL to auth.

This is what i'm using

```
<?php
// this works like a charm
echo '<form action="https://mano.labas.lt/prisijungimo_patikrinimas" method="post">';

echo '<input name="_username" value="username"/>';
echo '<input name="_password" value="password"/>';
echo '<input type="submit"/>';

echo '</form>';

// this one on the other hand is not
//The username or email address of the account.
define('USERNAME', 'user');

//The password of the account.
define('PASSWORD', 'pass');

//Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');

//Where our cookie information will be stored (needed for authentication).
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');

//URL of the login form.
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://mano.labas.lt/prisijungimo_patikrinimas');

//Login action URL. Sometimes, this is the same URL as the login form.
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://mano.labas.lt/prisijungimo_patikrinimas');


//An associative array that represents the required form fields.
//You will need to change the keys / index names to match the name of the form
//fields.
$postValues = array(
    '_username' => USERNAME,
    '_password' => PASSWORD
);

//Initiate cURL.
$curl = curl_init();

//Set the URL that we want to send our POST request to. In this
//case, it's the action URL of the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);

//Tell cURL that we want to carry out a POST request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Set our post fields / date (from the array above).
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));

//We don't want any HTTPS errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Where our cookie details are saved. This is typically required
//for authentication, as the session ID is usually saved in the cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Sets the user agent. Some websites will attempt to block bot user agents.
//Hence the reason I gave it a Chrome user agent.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//Tells cURL to return the output once the request has been executed.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Allows us to set the referer header. In this particular case, we are
//fooling the server into thinking that we were referred by the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);

//Do we want to follow any redirects?
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

//Execute the login request.
curl_exec($curl);

//Check for errors!
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

//We should be logged in by now. Let's attempt to access a password protected page
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mano.labas.lt/');

//Use the same cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Use the same user agent, just in case it is used by the server for session validation.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//We don't want any HTTPS / SSL errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Execute the GET request and print out the result.
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

and I get redirected to http://mano.labas.lt/prisijungti (this link is for login).

Can someone explain me why is this not working?

By the way: My username have + symbol in its name, maybe that could make a difference